# How do I make these functions rearrange the names, and take the average of the scores?

Tags: python

I am trying to get these function to take information from a text file. Then take the names and the scores associated with them, then take the average of the scores and print them in an ordered list.

[list of what I am suppose to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhDMh.png)

[the sample text to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh43T.png)

```
t = open('sample-1.txt','r')

line = t.readlines()
count=0

for i in line:
    count += 1
    print(i.strip())

t.close()

print('\nNew list with added name: ')
t2 = open('sample-1.txt','a')
t2.writelines("\nAaron Woods 1122 123 324 45 88 1561 9 18")
t2.close()

t3=open('sample-1.txt','r')
line2=t3.readlines()
count2 = 0 

for j in line2:
    count2+=1
    print(j.strip())
t3.close()

t4= open('sample-1.txt','r')

def order_nam (str_1,str_2):
    count3=0

def avg_1(num_avg): 
    count4=0
    for k in range(len(2)): # was trying to make it where it would hopefully ignore the names and just get the numbers
        count4+=1
    return count4

new_avg= avg_1(t4) # was hoping this would send to def avg_1
nam_list=[]

print(new_avg)
```

I tried making some functions in order to sort names and calculate some averages. I tried sending the file to the function to calculate the average, but got an error when it got to it.

Comment: Your hope was correct, `avg_1(t4)` does send `t4` to `avg_1`. However, it seems that `avg_1` doesn't do anything with it. Why not?

Comment: Style suggestion: use context managers. E.g. `with open('sample-1.txt','r') as t: ...`

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am unsure as to why it is not doing anything with it, is the function not setup properly?

Comment: `avg_1` receives an argument `num_avg`, but it isn't used inside the function. What did you intend the function `avg_1` to do with the argument `num_avg`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I was trying to have it go through the file and only collect the numbers in it, so that I could then add them up to take the average of each score.